# fopen crashing in response to unrelated char buffer

Tags: c++, fopen

So I have a C++ function that takes in a string and a flag and writes them to a log according to the flag. After appropriately filling a char buffer that will be written to file I call an fopen. This fopen crashes consistently(for the most part) based on certain random input. Here's the code:

```
int log_command(char* source, int flag)
{

char *log_file_name = "db.log";
char *buffer = NULL;

int rc = 0;
SYSTEMTIME st;
FILE *fhandle = NULL;

switch(flag){
    case 0:
        buffer = (char*)calloc(1, strlen(source)+ 18/* 18: size for timestamp, quotes and \0 */);
        GetSystemTime(&st);
        sprintf(buffer, "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d \"%s\"\n", st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, source);
        break;
    case ROLLFORWARD:
        sprintf(buffer, "RF_START\n");
        break;
    case BACKUP:
        sprintf(buffer, "BACKUP %s", source);
        break;
}

printf("fopen attempt\n");
// Print buffer info for stackoverflow
printf("%s\n", buffer);
print_mem(buffer, strlen(buffer));

if( (fhandle = fopen(log_file_name, "a") ) == NULL ){ // Randomly crashes
    rc = FILE_OPEN_ERROR;
}
else{
    printf("fopen success\n");
    if(info) printf("Logging to %s: \"%s\" \n", log_file_name, buffer);
    fwrite(buffer, strlen(buffer), 1, fhandle);
    fclose(fhandle);
}

return rc;
}
```

When the buffer has the following text in it:

```
20160513050408 "insert into other values(120)"
```

and raw byte data like:

```
32 30 31 36 30 35 31 33  30 35 30 34 30 38 20 22  20160513050408 "
69 6e 73 65 72 74 20 69  6e 74 6f 20 6f 74 68 65  insert into othe
72 20 76 61 6c 75 65 73  28 31 32 30 29 22 0a     r values(120)".
```

It'll crash consistently for a while.. and then just work out of no where. When *source has, say 4, 176, or most any other number instead of 120 it works just fine.

Comment: There's a lot of C in your C++. Have you considered using `std::string`, `std::ofstream`, etc?

Comment: Is this C or C++? `char *log_file_name = "db.log";` is not valid C++.

Comment: Your parameters to `calloc` are swapped over. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc

Comment: Have you tried running it in the debugger?

Comment: You have added one four-digit number, five two-digit numbers, two quote characters, a space, a newline, and a null terminator. Does it add up to 18? (Why on God's green earth do you want a newline in a filename?)

Comment: Count again; your `sprintf` prints a minimum of 19 characters + the strlen (and may print more).  You should use `snprintf` to prevent buffer overflow. (Hint: the numbers in the `%d` are a minimum size, not a maximum size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allocating enough characters for `buffer`. As a consequence, you end up writing over memory that you are not supposed to, which leads to undefined behavior.

You are using the following format in the call to `sprintf`.

```
"%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d \"%s\"\n"
```

The needs of that format specifier are:

1. `4` characters for `st.wYear`
2. `2` characters for `st.wMonth`
3. `2` characters for `st.wDay`
4. `2` characters for `st.wMonth`
5. `2` characters for `st.wMinute`
6. `2` characters for `st.wSecond`
7. `1` character for the space character
8. `1` character for `"`
9. `strlen(source)` characters for `source`
10. `1` character for `"`
11. `1` character for `\n`
12. `1` character for the terminating null character.

You need at least `strlen(source) + 19` characters.

Change

```
buffer = (char*)calloc(1, strlen(source)+ 18);
```

to

```
buffer = (char*)calloc(strlen(source) + 19, 1);  // Make it 19 or higher.
```